# C# - Calling a function from static main

Tags: c#, static, program-entry-point, function-calls

my question is probably very basic but I did not find an answer...

I wrote a function (public checkSomething that gets 2 strings) in program.cs
when I tried to call this function from static main
I got this error:

> "An object reference is required for a non-static field, method or
>   property 'checkSomething(string,string)'  ".

However,when I changed my main to Public (and not static)- there is no error.
Why this happen? What is better - to have a Static main or not? Why would it even matter?

thanks!

Comment: Put your function as static, public static checkSomething(string x, string x2)

Comment: How much do you understand about what `static` means?

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault: That's not necessarily appropriate. We simply can't tell with so little information. All that seems clear at the moment is that the OP should learn more about the meaning of `static` - and SO isn't as good a way to do that as via a book or good tutorial, IMO.

Comment: Read some more on static classes/members -> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: I'd say read a little about classes and instances of classes before reading on `static`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question here is not about static functions, but specifically why is `main` static in a `C#` application.

It has to do with having only one thread for the main application. This is defined when using the `[STAThread]` attribute on the main function. The executing thread enters the main function only once, and no instance of the `Program` class is required.

The static main function can then instantiate any classes it requires for normal operation. These are often things like forms, or worker classes.

The program either enter a message loop in the main thread to process a visible form, or the program terminates.

When you remove the static reference for main the `build options` for the project switch from a `startup function` to a `startup object`, and an instance of the class is created before `main` is called.

It's a matter of personal preference, but keep in mind that only 1 main is ever executed during start up.

Comment: +1 for not only answering the exact question, but for being able to descent to a more beginner level and give an answer that helps, and not discipline the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Main method should be static so you can't call non static methods from static method.

change checkSomething to static.

if main method is not static then we need to create instance to call the main method. To create instant again we need to excute some code! Thats why I think this starting point `Main` make Static.